# Trying to return custom 404 page instead nginx 404 default page

Tags: nginx, vue.js

I have SPA made with Vue.js.

I handle 404 at client side this way:

```
//at the end of router
{
  path: '/404',
  name: 'not-found',
  component: () => import(...)
},
{
  path: '*',
  redirect: '/404'
}
```

**Problem**: when I'm trying to access some unexisting page on my dev environment, I got nginx default 404 page instead my Vue page.

Parts of Nginx config:

```
server {
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    //ssl config managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = <...>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name <...>;
    listen 80;
}
server {
    if ($host = <...>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name <...>;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Locally I don't have such problems, my local config also has `try_files $uri =404;` row.
What's wrong?

I've tried

```
location / {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

instead

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

, didn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server{    
 error_page 404 $scheme://$host/404;
}
```